# gfs declared on server.js, i want to retrieve the files on files.js and cant use gfs.files.find() because gfs is decleared on server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

so I have connected Gridfs to MongoDB on server.js as shown below

```
     //connect to mongodb
      mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true }, 
         function(err){
           if(err){
              console.log(err)
           }
      });

      var conn = mongoose.connection;


     conn.once('open', function() {
       console.log('-connection open to database-');

         // intialize stream
         var gfs = grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo, )
         gfs.collection('uploads');


    })
```

so now I want to retrieve the files that are stored on gridfs collection uploads, but I can't use gfs.files.find() because I am on a different file: files.js. is there a way to fix this? thankyou.

```
            gfs.files.find().toArray((err,files)=>{
             console.log(files)
            })
```

Comment: Are you using [expressJS](https://expressjs.com/)?

Comment: no, the app is working right i have all the modules i just need a way of exporting gfs.collection('uploads'); and call it on a different file